# NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Validation occurs even validation-api 1.1.0.Final in the POM

Tags: java, hibernate, mule, mule-studio

Looks strange... I have exception trace:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
        at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleInvoker.invoke(MuleInvoker.java:117)
        at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleJAXWSInvoker.invoke(MuleJAXWSInvoker.java:47)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:123)
        at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor.sendToDestination(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:295)
        at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor.process(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:136)
        at org.mule.module.cxf.config.FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.process(FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.java:52)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
        at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
        at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:101)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
        at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
        at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
        at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
        at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
        at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
        at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:44)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
        at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
        at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$1.process(AbstractPipeline.java:112)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor
        ....
        at org.mule.execution.FlowProcessingPhase$1.run(FlowProcessingPhase.java:63)
        at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.comp.db.utils.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:51)
        at com.comp.db.DAO.ApplicationDAOImpl.getPcoApplicationIBStatus(ApplicationDAOImpl.java:62)
        at com.comp.serv.ServiceEndPoindImpl.getApplicationStatus(ServiceEndPoindImpl.java:641)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.mule.model.resolvers.AbstractEntryPointResolver.invokeMethod(AbstractEntryPointResolver.java:151)
        at org.mule.model.resolvers.MethodHeaderPropertyEntryPointResolver.invoke(MethodHeaderPropertyEntryPointResolver.java:112)
        at org.mule.model.resolvers.DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.invoke(DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.java:39)
        at org.mule.component.DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.invoke(DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.java:343)
        at org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.invokeComponentInstance(AbstractJavaComponent.java:86)
        at org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.doInvoke(AbstractJavaComponent.java:77)
        at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.invokeInternal(AbstractComponent.java:126)
        at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.access$000(AbstractComponent.java:61)
        at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent$1$1.process(AbstractComponent.java:242)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    ......

        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:127)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyBeanValidationConstraintsOnDDL(Configuration.java:1674)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyConstraintsToDDL(Configuration.java:1624)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1415)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1826)
        at com.comp.db.utils.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:44)
        ... 110 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:118)
        ... 115 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Validation
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:342)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:106)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

I read the https://stackoverflow.com/a/17142416/1293060 and now my dependency tree looks like:

```
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20151123:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- fife:rsyntaxtextarea:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.neovisionaries:nv-i18n:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.fluttercode.datafactory:datafactory:jar:0.8:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.testng:testng:jar:6.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.48:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4:compile
[INFO] +- org.mule:mule-core:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.stephenc.eaio-uuid:uuid:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.stephenc.eaio-grabbag:grabbag:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm-commons:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- asm:asm-tree:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.mvel:mule-mvel2:jar:2.1.9-MULE-003:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jgrapht:jgrapht-jdk1.5:jar:0.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.common:mule-common:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-spring-config:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-annotations:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-http:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-ssl:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- tomcat:tomcat-util:jar:5.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- tomcat:tomcat-apr:jar:5.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.samba.jcifs:jcifs:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-client:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-cxf:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-aegis:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jibx:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-common:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jibx:jibx-run:jar:1.2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xpp3:xpp3:jar:1.1.3.4.O:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jibx:jibx-schema:jar:1.2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.jibx:jibx-extras:jar:1.2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-local:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-common-utilities:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.6.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.5.1-1:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.opensaml:openws:jar:1.4.2-1:compile
[INFO] |  |           \- org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.3.2-1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-rm:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-management:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-common:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-wstx-msv-validation:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.java.dev.msv:msv-core:jar:2011.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd:xsdlib:jar:2010.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- isorelax:isorelax:jar:20030108:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- relaxngDatatype:relaxngDatatype:jar:20020414:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml.soap:saaj-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-spring-security:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-spring-extras:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-builders:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-tcp:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.saxon:saxon:jar:9.1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-annotation_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.jws:jsr181-api:jar:1.0-MR1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.7.0:runtime
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.7.0:runtime
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-management:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- mx4j:mx4j-jmx:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- mx4j:mx4j-impl:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- mx4j:mx4j-tools:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- mx4j:mx4j-remote:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.yourkit:yjp-controller-api-redist:jar:9.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- tanukisoft:wrapper:jar:3.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-xml:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.3.4.O:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.java.dev.stax-utils:stax-utils:jar:20080702:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.saxon:saxon:jar:dom:9.1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.saxon:saxon:jar:xqj:9.1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-interceptor-module:jar:3.5-M2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
```

But after deploying i still receive `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Validation` error (see stacktrace of root cause). Could you help to avoid this exception? Thank you.

**UPDATE**
Now my pom has dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

<!--

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
-->
```

and dependencies tree:

```
 \- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.3.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.1.0:compile
```

And the exception is the same:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.Validation
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

I will be glad for any ideas and help.

**UPDATE**

Also tried to add `hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl=false` into app.properties and `<scope>test</scope>` into `<artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>`. Doesn't help.

**UPDATE**
Also tried to delete `validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar` from folder of deployed application.

**UPDATE**
This :

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
      <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
              <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
  </dependency>
```

doesn't help too. =(

**Update**

This case also doesn't work:

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
```

**UPDATE**
Doesn't work too:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>


       <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

        </dependency>-->


       <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
```

Help still needed.

**May be problem in Mule 3.4 libraries?**

Comment: have you tried a `mvn clean` and redeploy?

Comment: Yes, tried `clean package -U -Dmaven.test.skip=true`

Comment: can you take a look into your war, if the Validation jar is there?

Comment: @Jens, it is not war, but jars are in the folder http://snag.gy/4euly.jpg

Answer (score 1):

And add this jar:

```
  hibernate-validator-5.x.x
```

And remove `javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final` and `validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final` because  is not compatible with hibernate-validator.

Comment: Added, but now `Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:127)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyBeanValidationConstraintsOnDDL(Configuration.java:1674)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyConstraintsToDDL(Configuration.java:1624),,,`

Comment: I excluded   `<artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>` from pom, then `mvn clean -U` , but it still in tree  `\- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.3.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.1.0:compile`

Comment: @May12 remove :validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final

Comment: how? I removed it from pom. Is it enough?

Comment: @May12 try to post all your material i'll try to run it

Comment: Abdelhak, on the local machine it works fine. The problem occurs when i deploy it  on test environment. That is the cause why i can't provide you with materials.

Comment: @May12 try to control in your file lib that all jar been

Answer (score 0):

Check the Target folder or the deployed location on the server to ensure the jar is available.

Comment: Does it have validation jar too ?

Comment: @Sarhiesh, there are nex files in the folder C:\mule-standalone\apps\services\lib : `antlr-2.7.6.jar
bsh-2.0b4.jar
commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-pool-1.3.jar
datafactory-0.8.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
hibernate-core-3.6.2.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar
jcommander-1.48.jar
json-20151123.jar
jta-1.1.jar
junit-4.12.jar
nv-i18n-1.9.jar
ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar
rsyntaxtextarea-2.0.1.jar
sqljdbc4-4.0.jar
testng-6.9.10.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar`

Comment: Also I tried to delete validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar from folder of deployed application.

Comment: Also I tried to delete validation-api-x.x.x.jar from folder of deployed application.

Answer (score 0):

Old post but thought I give an update: 
I have tried different versions of **hibernate-validator** artifact but still had the same error. 
So I copied the **validation-api-xxx.jar** to one of the "parent" class loader locations;

- In Mule Studio I put this under **plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.4.0_3.4.0.201310241917\mule\user**
- On the server I have it under **$MULE_HOME/lib/apps//mule**

This fixes the problem. But I have not yet figured out why only including the hibernate-validator in the POM would not work.

Oh I forgot to mention, make sure to leave the hibernate-validator artificact in your POM.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Make sure that the validation-api version you use matches what is required by the hibernate-validator. You can look that up in the dependency list

Answer (score 0):

We use mule 3.4 Community Edition. This is what works for us:

Remove

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>`
```

from your pom.xml.

Make sure to add **validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar** in mule's user library directory; if you are using *mule studio* it should be in **plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.3.4.0_3.4.0.201310241917\mule\user**. If using *mule server* you should place the file in **mule/lib/user**

We have at least one server where placing the validation jar in the user directory causes class loading issues, but fortunately for use, we don't really need *hibernate's jpa validation*; so we disable validation altogether. Then *validation.jar* will totally be ignored by class loaders - it would not care if it is present or not. Here is how we achieve that:

```
 <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="my.pkg.to.scan" />
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
     <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
  </property>
  <property name="jpaProperties">
     <props>
        <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop> -->
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        <!--  set the JPA provider validation-mode to NONE -->
        <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
     </props>
  </property>
```

The key line here is `<prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>`